# what does "Never far from the surface"mean?

Tags: expressions

i see this phrase in this sentence:Never far from the surface, a dark, dystopian view of artificial intelligence (AI) has returned to the headlines, thanks to British physicist Stephen Hawking.

Read more: http://www.businessinsider.com/afp-artificial-intelligence-hawkings-fears-stir-debate-2014-12#ixzz3LELE6nfQ

Comment: Surely this is General Reference? It's just a metaphorical usage where ***surface*** evokes the "top layer" of humanity's collective attention (as also represented by ***headlines*** - being "issues/events that people are currently interested in").

Comment: It means exactly what it says.

Comment: @tchrist When new users come to the site with something that is puzzling them, is it helpful to say "It means exactly what it says"? If OP understood it, they wouldn't be asking in the first place. Not all metaphors are obvious.

Comment: @tchrist: I respectfully suggest that it does *not* mean "exactly what it says", since what we have here is a *metaphoric* usage (not that far removed from [***floated across** his consciousness*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22floated+across+his+consciousness%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)). But to a first approximation, ***all language is metaphor***.

Answer (score 1):

The turn-of-phrase means something isn't completely buried and is liable to rise again, (or come out of hiding) at any time. For instance, "*political correctness simply masks prejudices that are never far from the surface*." Given certain conditions what is buried, hidden or masked by convention or laws, still exists.